# Field not being inserted into mysql database from php

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a little problem where a field is not being inserted into my users table. I have two tables as follows:

users - id, gamerid, email, password, country, country_code
countries - country_id, country, country_code

Now i have a signup form that comprises of gamerid,email,password and a country select (pulls from the countries table using php)

My problem is that when i submit the form, i want to run a query to pull the country code from the table which matches what was selected by the user and insert these fields into the users table. All my data is inserting correctly except for the country_code.

Here is my code for the html select section:

```
    <select name = "country_create" style = "height: 25px; width: 180px;">
    <option value="0" selected="selected" class =  "signup_form_country_select_class">Select your country</option>
    <?php
        include "config.php";

        $connection = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db($dbname, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

        $result = mysql_query('SELECT country FROM countries');

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo '<option value="'.$row['country'].'">'.$row['country'].'</option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

And here is the php from the register script:

```
    $connection = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

// INPUT CLEANING FUNCTION
function clean($str)
{
    $cleaned = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($str));
    return $cleaned;
}

$gamerid = clean($_POST['gamerid_create']);
$email = clean($_POST['email_create']);
$password = clean($_POST['password_create']);
$country = ($_POST['country_create']);

$cc_qry = "SELECT country_code FROM countries WHERE country = '$country'";
$country_code = mysql_query($cc_qry);

$insert = "insert into users(gamerid,email,password,country,country_code) values('$gamerid','$email','$password','$country','$country_code')";                    
mysql_query($insert, $connection);
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: *$country_code = mysql_query($cc_qry);* This is not what you think it is, its a resource

Comment: Your `clean()` function is fine but you need to use it for ALL values that go to the database. As is you have SQL Injection vulnerabilities. Even better use placeholders in PDO.

Comment: @AliGajani what has codeigniter to do with this?

Answer (score 5):

First - use PDO or mysqli functions, but secondly - you must also fetch data from query result:

```
$res = mysql_query($cc_qry);
$res_cc = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$country_code = $res_cc['country_code'];
```